# AIR dispatch event with parameter

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have a form with a search field.
When user press enter key, I use httpservice to send a query to mySQL database.
In some case (a lot) there are several record, so a new window is opening to show those record with a datagrid to let user chose the good result.

My problem is how to send selected information to the first window (with text field).
I gess that dispatch event is the way but I don't found how to use!

Can you help me to find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: How are you creating the new window?  Is it an actual new NativeWindow? Or are you using the term generically to refer to another screen in your application?

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly but here goes: subclass event so it can contain a data-field and dispatch that in the "other" window

Comment: The first window is a custom window extend Window (create with myCustomWindo.open(true). For second window I hesitate between popup PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, TextAreaWindow); and other option is to create a window as the first. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to communicate within an MDI environment I suggest that you use some kind of shared model ( aka Mediator or Presentation Model ) that keeps a contract between the desired windows.

```
class SelectionPM{
     [Bindable]
     public var selectedItem:Object;
}
```

**Use case:**

> Window1 has an instance of SelectionPM, when you open Window2 you pass
>   SelectionPM instance to it, then update SelectionPM.selectedItem
>   property on changing selection in the Window2 datagrid.  That will
>   propagate the binding chain up to Window1, where you can use the
>   SelectionPM.selectedItem as you wish.

Ideally you would use an IoC container for model injection but that is another story.

That might seem like a lot of work but if you keep this methodology across your app you will benefit from it.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for answer but it's seems to be difficult for a newbie like me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a set of four classes as a basis.  Obviously you don't want to be doing the actual work in the constructors as below.

```
public class App
{
    public static var eventDispatcher:EventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
    public function App()
    {
        new Window1();
    }
}

class AppEvent extends Event
{
    public static const DATA_READY:String = "APPEVENT.DATA_READY";
    public var data:Object;
    public function AppEvent( type:String, data:Object )
    {
        super( type );
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class Window1
{
    public function Window1()
    {
        App.eventDispatcher.addEventListener( AppEvent.DATA_READY, onDataReady );
        ...DO STUFF...
        new Window2();
    }
    private function onDataReady( evt:AppEvent ) : void
    {
        ...DO STUFF WITH "evt.data"....
    }
}

class Window2
{
    public function Window2()
    {
        ...GET DATA FROM SERVER AND PUT IT IN "data"...
        App.eventDispatcher.dispatchEvent( new AppEvent( AppEvent.DATA_READY, data ) );
    }
}
</pre>
```